# Iframe element not auto delete the content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Any idea why at [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvpx63nk/) the iframe is auto deleting its content? How can i overcome this error?

**HTML**

```
<iframe id = "Preview"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
document.ready = (function(){
document.getElementById('Preview').src = "about:blank";
var iframe = document.getElementById('Preview'),
    iframedoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    iframedoc.body.innerHTML = "<html>To preview the xml/gml file visit<a href = 'about:blank' target = '_blank'></a></html>";
    alert()
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are setting the src of the iframe.
You just have to get rid of :
    `document.getElementById(' Preview ').src = " about:blank ";`